# MIN and DISTINCT for ORACLE DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query

```
SELECT table_article.articleID, table_article_to_date.sellDate, MIN(table_article.price) AS minPrice
FROM table_article table_article
LEFT JOIN table_article_to_date table_article_to_date ON (table_article.ord_no=table_article_to_date.ord_no)
WHERE table_article.price > 0 AND table_article_to_date.sellDate BETWEEN_TWO_DATES
GROUP BY table_article.articleID, table_article_to_date.sellDate, table_article.price
```

For the sell_date I use a time range. My problem is, that i get more than one entrie each articleID.
I wish to have the lowest price of each articleID in a specified time range. DISTINCT is not woking with MIN

Givs a change to make this with a query?

Comment: remove the `table_article.price` from the `GROUP BY`. You are trying to get the MIN, so no need to group by this column

Comment: Thank you  @Roy Bogado. So I get for each day an output. I need only an output from the smallest price in the complete time range.

Comment: @Koda: sample data, actual and desired
 results would help clarifying your question.

Comment: If you what just the MIN price, remove all from the `select` (except the `min`) and remove the `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are adding the sell date to the GROUP BY clause. TO solve the issue, you need to take it out and make use of subqueries to get it back. To achieve this, you can do an inner join of the query and a query with the id, sell date and prize on the id and prize.
Also, no need for the prize in the group by, since it's already in the MIN.

```
SELECT articleData.articleId, articleData.sellDate, articleData.price FROM
  (
    SELECT articleId, MIN(price)
    FROM table
    [...]
    GROUP BY articleId
  ) AS minPrice
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT articleId, sellDate, price
    FROM table
  ) AS articleData
  ON minPrice.price = articleData.price AND minPrice.articleId = articleData.articleId
```

Comment: Thank you. INNER JOIN is new for me. I will try it. Thank you. Have you a sample for me?

Comment: I edited the answer with a code example. INNER JOIN is a normal join, it does not join the NULLs

Comment: Thank you. sellDate is not in articleDate. I think I can add the left join for sellDate in both query?

Comment: Correct, you can do the LEFT JOIN  to get the data

Comment: Thank you. With your Query I tet: ORA-00907 missing right paranthesis

Comment: Check that you close all the parenthesis you are opening

Comment: Yes. There are closed like your example